# Mesos Framework to optimally distribute short (2-10 second) tasks

Tags: scheduled-tasks, cluster-computing, real-time, mesos

I need to execute short real-time tasks (i.e. each task has a deadline - typically 1-10 seconds) of various types.

Given a task of type A to be scheduled, I want Mesos to send the job to a slave that can meet the task deadline.

Optimally, the framework would:

1. Learn the resource requirements of each job-type automatically
2. Make suggestions for adding or removing slaves from the cluster based on load
3. Support dynamic re-prioritization of the tasks running on each slave

Would any of the existing Mesos frameworks be a good start for this?

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements of right-sizing tasks, auto-provisioning the cluster, and dynamic re-prioritization of tasks don't all fit into an existing framework that I know of (somebody correct me!), but Mesos makes it easy to build your own custom framework if you have these kinds of special needs.

For scheduling short tasks with existing frameworks, you could check out [Chronos](https://github.com/mesos/chronos), [Singularity](https://github.com/HubSpot/Singularity), or [Aurora](http://aurora.incubator.apache.org/).

If you want to try building your own framework (~200 lines of code for a PoC), check out the following links:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5P5nDa4Beuw
- http://mesosphere.github.io/presentations/mesoscon-2014/#/
- http://mesosphere.github.io/presentations/production-frameworks/#/

Comment: Chronos, Singularity and Aurora are all listed as being for long-running tasks. See http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/mesos-frameworks/

Comment: As listed on that page, Chronos is for batch scheduling, essentially a distributed cron with dependencies. Singularity and Aurora both support cron-like tasks as well as long-running tasks. From the Singularity description, "long running processes, one-off tasks, and scheduled jobs." And from Aurora's own webpage, "for long-running services and cron jobs."